# Can I add 3D objects as subfigures (using movie15)

Tags: beamer, floats, subfloats, 3d, movie15

I have faced one stiff problem that when I try to add four 3D plots (2 rows x 2 columns) in my beamer by using subfigure approach, I fail!

This is my minimal example:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering

\subfigure[Figure No.1]{\label{fig4a}\includemovie[poster,toolbar,
3Daac=7, 3Droll=0, 3Dc2c=0.000000 1.000000 0.000000, 3Droo=17.320508, 3Dcoo=0 0 0,3Dlights=CAD,]{0.3\linewidth}
{0.3\linewidth}{Files/plot1.u3d}}

\subfigure[Figure No.2]{\label{fig4b}\includemovie[poster,toolbar,
3Daac=7, 3Droll=0, 3Dc2c=0.000000 1.000000 0.000000, 3Droo=17.320508, 3Dcoo=0 0 0,3Dlights=CAD,]{0.2\linewidth}
{0.2\linewidth}{Files/plot2.u3d}} \\

\subfigure[Figure No.3]{\label{fig4c}\includemovie[poster,toolbar,
3Daac=7, 3Droll=0, 3Dc2c=0.000000 1.000000 0.000000, 3Droo=17.320508, 3Dcoo=0 0 0,3Dlights=CAD,]{0.3\linewidth}
{0.3\linewidth}{Files/plot3.u3d}}

\subfigure[Figure No.4]{\label{fig4d}\includemovie[poster,toolbar,
3Daac=7, 3Droll=0, 3Dc2c=0.000000 1.000000 0.000000, 3Droo=17.320508, 3Dcoo=0 0 0,3Dlights=CAD,]{0.2\linewidth}
{0.2\linewidth}{Files/plot4.u3d}}

\caption{Four 3D Plots}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Any help or any new suggested method!

Comment: Thanks Raincoat for your comment .. I have put the answer in a separate reply

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the above problem by using the old subfigure package .. I put it below just for helping anyone who may face similar problem:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includemovie[poster,toolbar,
3Daac=7, 3Droll=0, 3Dc2c=0.000000 1.000000 0.000000, 3Droo=17.320508, 3Dcoo=0 0 0,3Dlights=CAD,]{0.7\linewidth}{0.7\linewidth}{file1.u3d}
\caption{\scriptsize Sub caption1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includemovie[poster,toolbar,
3Daac=7, 3Droll=0, 3Dc2c=0.000000 1.000000 0.000000, 3Droo=17.320508, 3Dcoo=0 0 0,3Dlights=CAD,]{0.7\linewidth}{0.7\linewidth}{file2.u3d}
\caption{\scriptsize Sub caption2}
\end{subfigure}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includemovie[poster,toolbar,
3Daac=7, 3Droll=0, 3Dc2c=0.000000 1.000000 0.000000, 3Droo=17.320508, 3Dcoo=0 0 0,3Dlights=CAD,]{0.7\linewidth}{0.7\linewidth}{file3.u3d}
\caption{\scriptsize Sub caption3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includemovie[poster,toolbar,
3Daac=7, 3Droll=0, 3Dc2c=0.000000 1.000000 0.000000, 3Droo=17.320508, 3Dcoo=0 0 0,3Dlights=CAD,]{0.7\linewidth}{0.7\linewidth}{file4.u3d}
\caption{\scriptsize Sub caption4}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Main caption}
\label{figxx2}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `subfigure` package? The syntax used here is from the newer `subcaption` package, while that in the question is from `subfigure`. However, the key difference between this code and the one in your question is, I think, that you don't have paragraph breaks (empty lines) between each subfigure here. You didn't say *how* it failed, but  with the code in your question each subfigure will be placed on a separate line.

Comment: My last answer was written 3 months ago, and I just put it in a separate answer based on Raincoat recommendation .. Regarding your question: Based on my memory, I think the first code was put without spacing (paragraph breaks or empty lines) and it didn't work